# Access to Vagrant VM without Vagrant ssh

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I've been creating a Vagrant box and trying to do some different stuff like connecting to that virtual machine without `vagrant ssh`

I've had my ssh config like this

`Host virtual
    HostName     10.10.10.10  # Vagrant box ip
    User vagrant
    IdentityFile /Users/myuser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
    PasswordAuthentication no
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    IdentitiesOnly yes`

but when I try to connect using `ssh virtual` I got the prompt asking for the password.

So, Is there any way to be able to connect to Vagrant box  without `vagrant ssh`

Comment: Are you able to log in using the password `vagrant`? Are you using a base box which has the insecure key added?

Comment: Yes, I can access with `vagrant ssh` and I got the insecure key. The problem is when I try to access using `ssh [parameters]`

Answer (score 0):

You can add your public key into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in vagrant machine and then you can ssh virtual without password.